# Find image next to element

Tags: jquery, find, append

I'm trying to find the closest img next to some element. This element could be anything from h1 to a div. When finding this img I would like to append this to a div. This doesn't work for me:

```
img = $(this).parent().find('img').attr('scr');

$('#result').append('<img src="' + img + '"  />');
```

Don't know why this doesn't work.

Comment: We need to see html, your code will work given html that matches the selectors.

Comment: closest as in ancestor? sibling? descendant?

Comment: Should `.attr('scr')` be `.attr('src')`?

Comment: I realize my explanation was to short, apology

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a combination of `closest()` and `:has()`.

```
var img = $(this).closest(':has(img)').find('img').attr('src');

$('<img/>',{src: img}).appendTo('#result');
```

Comment: Thanks, this works very good:) I never encountered :has before, I would have never came up with this